Proving this function is convex
Let $C$ be a symmetric positive definite matrix such that $0\leq c_{ij} \leq 1$, $c_{ii}=1$, and define $f$ as $$f(x)=\sum_{i}x_{i}\log(\sum_{j}c_{ij}x_{j})$$ for positive vectors $x$ (in fact let's assume that $\sum_i x_i = 1$).  From every computational test I have done, this function appears to be convex, but I cannot figure out why.  Can anyone offer any advice for going about it?  It looks a lot like negative entropy but with a linear term inside the log.  Also, the individual summands are not convex, but their sum always appears to be.
Edit:  The Hessian is $$h_{ij} = \sum_{k}\frac{c_{ki}c_{kj}x_{k}}{(\boldsymbol{c}_{k}^{\top}\boldsymbol{x})^{2}}-\frac{c_{ij}}{\sum_{k}c_{ik}x_{k}}-\frac{c_{ji}}{\sum_{k}c_{jk}x_{k}}$$
Edit 2:  and the quadratic form for $n=2$ is $$\begin{array}{c}
-v_{1}{\left(v_{1}{\left(\frac{c_{11}^{2}x_{1}}{{\left(c_{11}x_{1}+c_{12}x_{2}\right)}^{2}}+\frac{c_{21}^{2}x_{2}}{{\left(c_{21}x_{1}+c_{22}x_{2}\right)}^{2}}-\frac{2\,c_{11}}{c_{11}x_{1}+c_{12}x_{2}}\right)}+v_{2}{\left(\frac{c_{11}c_{12}x_{1}}{{\left(c_{11}x_{1}+c_{12}x_{2}\right)}^{2}}+\frac{c_{21}c_{22}x_{2}}{{\left(c_{21}x_{1}+c_{22}x_{2}\right)}^{2}}-\frac{c_{12}}{c_{11}x_{1}+c_{12}x_{2}}-\frac{c_{21}}{c_{21}x_{1}+c_{22}x_{2}}\right)}\right)}\\
-v_{2}{\left(v_{1}{\left(\frac{c_{11}c_{12}x_{1}}{{\left(c_{11}x_{1}+c_{12}x_{2}\right)}^{2}}+\frac{c_{21}c_{22}x_{2}}{{\left(c_{21}x_{1}+c_{22}x_{2}\right)}^{2}}-\frac{c_{12}}{c_{11}x_{1}+c_{12}x_{2}}-\frac{c_{21}}{c_{21}x_{1}+c_{22}x_{2}}\right)}+v_{2}{\left(\frac{c_{12}^{2}x_{1}}{{\left(c_{11}x_{1}+c_{12}x_{2}\right)}^{2}}+\frac{c_{22}^{2}x_{2}}{{\left(c_{21}x_{1}+c_{22}x_{2}\right)}^{2}}-\frac{2\,c_{22}}{c_{21}x_{1}+c_{22}x_{2}}\right)}\right)}
\end{array}$$
Edit 3:  And per Geoffrey Irving's suggestion, if I set $y=Cx$, then the hessian is $h_{ij} = \frac{b_{ij}}{y_{i}}+\frac{b_{ji}}{y_{j}}$ for off-diagonals and $h_{ii} = \frac{2\,b_{ii}}{y_{i}}-\frac{\sum_{k}b_{ik}y_{k}}{y_{i}^{2}}$, where $b_{ij}$ is an entry of $C^{-1}$.

computing the Hessian of this function seems doable. Does it have a simple form? Can you include the Hessian in your post?

@ThomasKojar it was kind of ugly in sagemath, but I'll share what I have, thank you!

How can it be convex on positive vectors? If $n=1$,   this reduces to $f(x)=-x \log(x )$, which is concave and not convex…

@PietroMajer my mistake, the minus sign shouldn't have been there!  Thank you!

thanks. Can you also write down the quadratic form $v^t Hv$ for generic vector v, to see whether it is easy or not to get $v^tHv\geq 0$?by having the sums over i,j, might help you combine some terms. Because it seems there is some type of weighted Cauchy-Schwartz inequality here.

What if you change variables to $y = Cx$?

@ThomasKojar I entered in the quadratic form for $n=2$, maybe that will help with something :)

@GeoffreyIrving good idea!  I'll work out the corresponding terms for that one as well and edit...

@TomSolberg Can you write the quadratic form with the sums over i,j? I want to see a single summand to see whether we can do Cauchy Schwartz.

The function simplifies to
$$ \begin{align} f(x) &= \sum_i x_i \log\left(x_i + \sum_{j \neq i} c_{ij} x_j\right) \\ &= \underbrace{\sum_i x_i \log(x_i)}{\text{diagonal terms}} + \underbrace{\sum_i x_i \log\left(1 + \frac{\sum{j \neq i} c_{ij} x_j}{x_i}\right)}_{\text{off-diagonal terms}}\end{align}$$
The first expression is convex. The second one is concave.

@ndrwnaguib oh no!  So my conjecture is incorrect.  Thank you!

Not necessarily, but it'd be trickier now to show if we'd proceed with the Hessian test.
